# Is there a way to debug GNU Parallel?

Tags: gnu, gnu-parallel

I have an example script that I am trying to run:

```
#!/bin/zsh

echo "i,rt,fifo,depth,rate,burst" > sweep_srcq.csv

parallel --bar --gnu -j4 --header : \
    '
    sem --id 0 echo {i},{rt},{fifo},{depth},{rate},{burst} >> sweep_srcq.csv | cat'\
    ::: i 5 \
    ::: rt 0 1 \
    ::: fifo 1 \
    ::: rate 5 6 8 A D 14 21 32 64 \
    ::: depth 128 \
    ::: burst 1 \
```

When I run this this script on one of my machines, it executes perfectly and I see the result file:

```
i,rt,fifo,depth,rate,burst
5,0,1,128,8,1
5,0,1,128,5,1
5,0,1,128,A,1
5,0,1,128,6,1
5,0,1,128,D,1
5,0,1,128,14,1
5,0,1,128,21,1
5,0,1,128,32,1
5,0,1,128,64,1
5,1,1,128,5,1
5,1,1,128,6,1
5,1,1,128,8,1
5,1,1,128,A,1
5,1,1,128,D,1
5,1,1,128,14,1
5,1,1,128,21,1
5,1,1,128,32,1
5,1,1,128,64,1
```

But on one of my other machines, this code just does not execute..

My timer stays at `0s` and it basically just stays there until I kill it. Is there a way I can debug, what could be going wrong on my machine?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it is your complete script you could do this, which is shorter and faster:

```
echo "i,rt,fifo,depth,rate,burst" > sweep_srcq.csv

parallel --bar -j4 --header : echo {i},{rt},{fifo},{depth},{rate},{burst} \
  ::: i 5 \
  ::: rt 0 1 \
  ::: fifo 1 \
  ::: rate 5 6 8 A D 14 21 32 64 \
  ::: depth 128 \
  ::: burst 1 \
  >> sweep_srcq.csv
```

But I get the feeling this is not your complete script and there is a reason why you call `sem` from `parallel`.

The first thing that strikes me is that you redirect stdout twice:

```
sem [...] >> sweep_srcq.csv | cat
```

Do you want stdout appended to .csv? Or do you want it sent to `cat`? If you want both, you should instead use `tee -a`.

Your problem could simply be that the servers interpret this line differently and that the stalled server runs a `cat` that reads from your keyboard.